# Alternative way to define cluster nodes property in spring-data-redis

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-redis, missing-features

I was trying to use spring-data-redis in my project. When I configure redis nodes in yaml file like:

```
spring:
  redis:
    cluster:
      max-redirects: 2
      nodes: host1:6379,host1:6380,host1:6381
```

Then, spring-data-redis creates the JedisConnectionFactory for cluster internally. But If I try to configure by following ways:

```
spring:
  redis:
    cluster:
      max-redirects: 2
      nodes: 
        - host1:6379
        - host1:6380
        - host1:6381
```

Then, I must have to create the bean of **JedisConnectionFactory** for cluster in my application.

I guess current version of spring-data-redis not supporting representation of number of nodes in array way in yaml to create cluster.

My suggestion is can spring-boot/spring-data-redis developer supports above format of yaml to create redis cluster internally?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you check [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-redis/blob/master/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/redis/connection/RedisClusterConfiguration.java#L71), it is possible to supply the hostAndPort as an ugly looking array like this, separate from `spring.redis` properties group;

```
clusterHostAndPorts:
  - host1:6379
  - host1:6380
  - host1:6381
```

Tested on my local, and it does work, the way you are asking is not supported, can see it [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-redis/blob/master/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/redis/connection/RedisClusterConfiguration.java#L89), then [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-redis/blob/master/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/redis/connection/RedisClusterConfiguration.java#L175), and then finally [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-redis/blob/master/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/redis/connection/RedisClusterConfiguration.java#L182).

> HostAndPort need to be seperated by  ':'.
>
> Host and Port **String** needs to specified as host:port